# Access the list of push notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

On iOS is there a way to access the list of push notifications that have been presented to the user?

I know there are some smart watches that are able to show on their dispalys the received notifications in real time, so there's probably an API to obtain the information.

Answer (score 3):

Push notifications are only accessible to the app that registered to receive them. The smart watches that you mentioned probably connects to the iPhone via Bluetooth, and uses [Apple Notification Center Service (ANCS)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html) to access notifications.

Local notifications are all you can get. The following line lists all currently scheduled ones:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]
```